# Google REST API Support Team Drive Isn't Working

Tags: python, rest, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to replace a file that's currently in a Team Drive folder with a new version. I have the following basis python function:

```
self.service.files().create(body=meta, media_body=media_body).execute()
```

This function works wonderfully for normal Google Drive files, but for the one(s) in Team Drive, I get a 404 "File not found" error.

I suspect this has to do with needing `supportTeamDrives` as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-teamdrives

However, if I do:

```
self.service.files().create(body=meta, media_body=media_body,
                            supportTeamDrive=True).execute()
```

I get the error `Got an unexpected keyword argument "supportTeamDrive"`. And if I try to put it in the `body` dictionary, I just get the same 404 error.

Why isn't this working, and how do I fix it to support Team Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor typo -- the paramater is `supportsTeamDrives`, not `supportTeamDrives`. I've made this mistake too :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy. Turns out there's actually a typo on Google's api documentation! I'm so glad you were able to point me to the right key. I'll send Google feedback too, so hopefully they'll fix it on their api page.

Comment: @elliptica geat catch! I submitted a bug report to Google support

Comment: As an add-on to this question, this command works great when using "drive" but not "sheets". E.g. service.spreadsheets.get(fileId=fileID, supportsTeamDrives=True) doesn't recognize the supportsTeamDrives parameter. How can we use the sheets API with Team Drive?